# only showing largest number while i want to print all numbers between two integers

Tags: java

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(T1.getText());
int b = Integer.parseInt(T2.getText());
int i;

if(a>b) {
    for(i=b;i<=a;i++) {
        jTextField3.setText(""+i);
    }
}

if(b>a) {
    for(i=a;i<=b;i++) {
        jTextField3.setText(""+i);
    }
}
```

it shows only highest number between 'a' and 'b'.
While i want to print all numbers between these two integers.

Comment: you have not initialized the value of `i`

Comment: @Nehal that's not the problem. Yeah sure it's bad coding practice what he's doing but i gets initialized when the loop starts.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are not appending to the text, you are overwriting it every time.

Your best bet is to first build the text you want and then sit it in one go on the UI textfield, that's the most efficient as it won't be triggering many spurious UI events:

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
for(i=b;i<=a;i++)
{
    b.append(i).append(' ');
}
jTextField3.setText(b.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are setting value of textField every time to a new i´s value. You should first concate all the i´s value and then set it to the textField.

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(T1.getText());
int b = Integer.parseInt(T2.getText());
String s = "";

int i;
  if(a>b)
{
for(i=b;i<=a;i++)
{
 s = s + " " + i;
}

}
if(b>a)
{
for(i=a;i<=b;i++)
{
 s = s + " " + i;
}

}
jTextField3.setText(s);
```

Comment: Please don't post code without supporting text.  You should explain what changes you have made and how they address the OP's problem.  Help others to understand.

Comment: I think I have changed the answer but don´t know why that didn´t come. Due to some network error. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

`setText()` will overwrite anything that you've previously set so at the end of the loop, only the last number (the biggest) will show in your text field.

You'll have to change what's in your loop to:

```
String s = "";

for (...) {
    s += ""+i;
}

jTextField3.setText(s);
```

This will keep concatenating new values to the end of the string `s` and finally set the text after your loop is finished.